# In C++ trying to write a newline after each operator overload cascade

Tags: c++, stream, operator-overloading, endl

this is a bit of a hard nut to crack. I'm writing a logging function that is trying to have a similar look to the std::cout

So basically the goal is to have the following code do as commented

```
   log << "text"; // This would output "text\n";
   log << "some " << "text"; //This would output "some text\n"
   log << "some number "<< 5; //This would output "some number 5\n"
```

I've tried using variadic templates, but didn't get far.
Here's the most successful attempt so far:

```
#include <iostream>

// stream_newliner works by just taking the address of an ostream you
// give it, and forwarding all writes (via operator<<) to that ostream.
// Then, when it finally destructs, it writes the newline.
template <typename CharT, typename Traits>
class stream_newliner
{
public:
// The constructor just takes the address of the stream you give it.
explicit stream_newliner(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& s) :
    p_s_{&s}
{}

// Boilerplate move construction. Nothing special here.
stream_newliner(stream_newliner&& s) : p_s_{nullptr}
{
    *this = std::move(s);
}

// On destruction, write the newline. (Note we check the pointer for
// null for technical reasons.)
~stream_newliner()
{
    if (p_s_)
    {
        // If you have std::unhandled_exceptions(), you can check to
        // see if a new exception is in flight, and only do the
        // newline if there's not.

        // Note that I'm writing an X and not a newline so you can
        // see it easier.
        (*p_s_) << 'X';
    }
}

// This is where the magic happens. Any time you do "x << y" where
// x is this type, it just passes it on to the underlying stream.
// When you do "x << y1 << y2", it all works magically because it
// translates to "operator<<(operator<<(x, y1), y2)"... and this
// function just passes each call to the underlying stream.
template <typename T>
auto operator<<(T&& t) -> stream_newliner<CharT, Traits>&
{
    (*p_s_) << std::forward<T>(t);
    return *this;
}

// Boilerplate move assignment. Nothing special here.
auto operator=(stream_newliner&& s) -> stream_newliner&
{
    std::swap(p_s_, s.p_s_);
    return *this;
}

// Technically don't need these, but it doesn't hurt to be explicit.
stream_newliner(stream_newliner const&) = delete;
auto operator=(stream_newliner const&) = delete;

   private:
// You could use a reference to the stream rather than a pointer,
// but references are harder to work with as class members.
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>* p_s_ = nullptr;
   };

   // Helper function to make it easier to create.
   template <typename CharT, typename Traits>
   auto line(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& s)
   {
return stream_newliner<CharT, Traits>{s};
   }

   auto main() -> int
   {
line(std::cout) << "foo";
std::cout << '\n';

line(std::cout) << 1 << ' ' << 2 << ' ' << 3;
std::cout << '\n';
   }
```

Comment: You can't do it. Each `<<` is a separate call to the operator, there's no way for it to know when it's the last one in the chain.

Answer (score 2):

I think this isn't too tricky. Let's see:

```
struct eol_log
{
    eol_log(std::ostream& os) : os_(os) {}
    ~eol_log() { os_ << '\n'; }

    template <typename T>
    std::ostream& operator<<(const T& t) && { return os_ << t; }

    std::ostream& os_;
};
```

Usage:

```
eol_log(std::cout) << "Foo" << "Bar" << 10;
eol_log(std::cout) << 10;
```

The temporary object acts as a kind of "full-expression guard".

If you'd rather have a permanent object that acts as your log sink, then you can wrap the above in a class, but now you need to move the state of being the last element along the chain:

```
class EolLogger
{
    class RvalLog
    {
        friend class EolLogger;

        RvalLog(std::ostream* os) : os_(os) {}
        RvalLog(RvalLog&& rhs) : os_(rhs.os_) { rhs.os_ = nullptr; }
        std::ostream* os_;

    public:
        template <typename T>
        RvalLog operator<<(const T& t) && { *os_ << t; return std::move(*this); }

        ~RvalLog() { if (os_) *os_ << '\n'; }
    };

    std::ostream& os_;

public:
    EolLogger(std::ostream& os) : os_(os) {}

    template <typename T>
    RvalLog operator<<(const T& t) { return RvalLog(&os_) << t; }
};
```

Usage:

```
EolLogger elog(std::cout);

elog << "Foo";
elog << 1 << 2 << 3;
```

Comment: Maybe should have called it `with_eol` or some such.

Comment: `eol_log` sounds like the Elf Tolkien left out.

Comment: Nice, however the goal is to have it use log << "text"; as opposed to log(steam)

Comment: @LemonCold: Updated with a different option.

Answer (score 1):

Someone posted this, and it sorta does the job.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Liner {
    bool Owned = true;
    Liner() = default;
    Liner(Liner &&O) { O.Owned = false; }
    ~Liner() { if (Owned) std::cout << '\n'; }
};

template <typename T>
const Liner &operator<<(const Liner &L, T &&E) {
    std::cout << std::forward<T>(E);
    return L;
}

struct SubLiner {
    operator Liner() const { return {}; }
};

const static SubLiner line;

int main() {
    line << "hello " << "world!";
    line << 1 << 2;
    line << 3;
    return 0;
}
```